# Embedding Google maps Street view

Tags: google-maps

im using this code to embed google maps on my website but im noire sure how id use the street view as default.

ROADMAP can be changed to SATELLITE, HYBRID or TERRAIN, but theres no option for streetview

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.864237, -4.251806);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Google doesn't offer embedding with street view. So you should go for some third party web apps.
You can simple embed map as an iframe. For example see below iframe code for Eifel Tower map with street view.

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://my.ctrlq.org/maps/#street|1|-151.33967789165447|13.83601756954612|48.8586|2.29405799999995"></iframe>
```

Details can be [found here](http://www.joelsays.com/embed-google-maps-with-street-view/)